# getStaticProps doesn't work when reload the page hosted on vercel

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

I am building nextjs project and facing the issues that one of the pages goes to 404 when reload the page.

I am using `getStaticProps` within the page directory.

```
pages
    - blogs.tsx
    - blog/[slug].tsx
    - index.tsx
    - _app.tsx
    - _document.tsx
```

Inside the `blogs.tsx` I call `getStaticProps` to get mdx file data to pass.

```
type BlogStaticInputs = {
    blogs: BlogsType[]
}

export const Index = ({ blogs }: BlogStaticInputs) => {
    return <Blogs blogs={blogs} />
}

// get all blogs data from './blogs'
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    console.log('Before getting blogs...')
    const blogs = getAllBlogs([
        'date',
        'description',
    ])

    return {
        props: { blogs }
    }
}
```

After I checked vercel deploy log, I noticed the `console.log('Before getting blogs...')` is printed out successfully in the first time, but when I go to page and reload there is no console.log output and just shows 404.

Being that said, nextjs cannot or tries to find some different page when I reload the `./blogs` page due to current `getStaticProps` implementation is not correct in some ways.

If someone have idea why current `getStaticProps` function doesn't fire and shows 404 as if the page doesn't exist only when reload the page.

When I first visit to `/blogs` page, it just works. But after I reload the page it goes to 404.

I already set trailingSlash = true since it seems one of the solutions but not working.

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

Comment: That's expected in production mode. [`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#write-server-side-code-directly) runs once at build time on the server, it doesn't get triggered on every request to the page. However, it does [run on every request in development mode](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#runs-on-every-request-in-development).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post answer by myself.

I figured it out I need to pass `as` parameter to specify the actual path in the `next/link` as below.

```
<Link
     href="/blogs"
     as={`/blogs`} <- this was required
     passHref
>
```